# How to access image in google drive from fusion table

Tags: google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to access an image from a fusion table since the fusion table doesn't support a byte array. I am putting my image in Google Drive and try to access the same image in a fusion table giving out the URL of the image.

I have created a service account to upload images to Google Drive, but I have to supply the URL into the fusion table. I don't know what URL to put in the fusion table, though I have the file ID for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API has a method to retrieve URLs for the self-link.

`file.getSelfLink();` returns you the link that can be accessed to show the resource image in my case.